# PHP Accessing a local API for JSON data

Tags: php, json

Trying to access data from a local API that outputs in JSON data, but I just keep getting:

> file_get_contents(/var/www/html/api/api.php?action=stats&user=testplayer): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set("display_errors", 1); 
include 'functions.php';

if(isset($_GET['action']))
{   
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
    try
    {
        switch($_GET['action'])
        {
            case 'stats':
            if(!isset($_GET['user']))
                    throw new Exception('Insufficient information : Username');
                    $user = $_GET['user'];
                    $url = htmlspecialchars_decode("/var/www/html/api/api.php?action=stats&user=$user");
                    $response = file_get_contents("$url");
                    $data = json_decode($response);
                    echo $data;
                    break;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
        echo json_encode(array('result' => 'error', 'cause' => $e->getMessage()));
    }
}   

?>
```

Is it not possible to pass ? and &s through file_get_contents?

Comment: You're trying to pass parameters to a local file path as if it was a URL?

Comment: You would need to make a web request for it to process the .php file, or make the API such that you can call the class directly with the parameters to generate the data (although this can bypass any extra web based checks etc.)

Comment: This seems a little drastic and somewhat presumptuous `header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');`

Comment: file_get_contents() expects a file location or an url, but you are mixing: passing a file location with params expecting to act as an url. It looks for the file but the location is wrong because of the ?...

Comment: Assuming this is your DocumentRoot `/var/www/html` then try `"locahost/api/api.php?action=stats&user=$user"`

Comment: You can make a function instead of call a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't process the php code if you are reading the file contents.

update the $url like this:

```
$url = htmlspecialchars_decode($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . "/api/api.php?action=stats&user=$user") ;
```

This will make the request to your apache server instead of reading the file contents.